# What is the namespace for DataBindingInterceptor?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am attempting to configure my NHibernate.Validator instance as described in this post

[Configuring Fluent NHibernate and NHibernate Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167615/configuring-fluent-nhibernate-and-nhibernate-validator)

However, I'm having some namespace ambiguity issues due to the way I've structured my project namespaces. As a result I need to fully qualify the DataBindingInterceptor class. For the life of me I can't find the namespace for this class. I've googled, stackoverflowed, and even tried with the object explorer.

Any help would be appreciated. If someone has links to good FNH/NH documentation I'd be really grateful, even on the project sites I can't really find good docs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataBindingInterceptor is not needed to configure NHV.  This is just something that the user in that post is doing in addition to configuring NHV.  You can also take a look at this post to configure NHV:

[NHibernate Validator not integrating with Fluent NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590250/nhibernate-validator-not-integrating-with-fluent-nhibernate)

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on the benefit of using the interceptor perhaps? I'm pretty new to FNH and not always sure why things are done in a particular way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that DatabindingInterceptor is a class that is somewhere in your code; it definitely isn't in the current NH/FNH namespaces.

[This MSDB blog entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx) has a sample DataBindingInterceptor class.